# Как работать с ОС в Java

Tags: java

Появился такой вопрос, можно ли с помощью java управлять операционной системой?
Например можно ли как то устанавливать пакеты в linux, управлять обновлением пакетов и т д?

Не нашел такой информации с лёту....

Comment: Открываем документацию по интересующему действию, вдумчиво читаем и выполняем в джава-коде

Comment: А в каком модуле это искать?
Это какая то API или работа с файлами или что? куда копать в данном направлении? В документации по Java вообще чёрт ногу сломит, не особо представляю в каком разделе даже это искать.

Comment: Даже если нет никаких джава-френдли API, всегда можно запустить процесс с командной строкой.

Comment: Это надо читать не в документации Java, а в документации ОС

Comment: `ProcessBuilder`, `Runtime.exec()`. Только это одна большая морока. Перенаправлять ввод и вывод, обрабатывать ошибки, показывать пользователю что случилось, спрашивать что теперь делать, запускать новые процессы и так по кругу